# Prove that these lines are perpendicular (orthogonal)...

Tags: graph-theory

According to the Law of mathematics, the product of slopes of $2$ perpendicular lines has to be $ -1 $.

Then, how do you prove that the following lines are perpendicular.

$x=4$ , $y=6 $

[image: Perpendicular lines]

My Calculation :

Slope of line $1$ ($x=4$) = Infinity

Slope of line $2$ ($y=6$) = $0$

Product of both slopes != $0$

Comment: That law satisfies with only those lines with finite tangents.

Comment: Hi Shuchang Zhang, Could you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Please see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519620/explain-why-perpendicular-lines-have-negative-reciprocal-slopes/519785#519785)

Answer (score 1):

write them in vector notation, the horizontal line is spanned by the vector $ ( x, 0)$ and the vertical line is spanned by the vector $(0,y)$
Now we apply dot product

$$ (x,0) * (0,y) = x0 + 0y = 0 \implies \; \; \text{Both lines are orthogonal by definition} $$